# What components should I check if the fridge is warm but the freezer is cold?

Tags: appliances

The freezer section of my Electrolux refrigerator model EI27BS16JW5 was cold but the refrigerator was warm. I removed some small amounts of ice buildup. Then I checked the operation of the fan motor and the damper and both were ok.

With the covers removed I was able to see the fan working and the damper in open position BUT no cold air was moving up to the refrigerator. The freezer remained cold but the refrigerator stayed at 65 degrees. Now after 2 days the refrigerator is suddenly working fine.

Is there anything in addition to the damper that controls air flow? Is the fan variable speed?

Comment: [Page 31 of the owners manual](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/56uwtu46v1-001412/electrolux-ei27bs16jw5-bottom-mount-refrigerator-parts) has some trouble shooting tips for precisely this situation. Have you look at those? I see no indication in the instructions that there are any variable speed fans. With all the "eco" settings, I'd imagine they'd loudly tout this as an "energy saving" feature it the fans were variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's inconvenient, but start with a full manual defrost. Ice in the air ducts or jamming the fans is a common cause of the condition you report.

Causes of ice buildup can be as obvious as a bad automatic defost (timer, heater, etc.) or as less-obvious as bad door seals or poorly covered/sealed foods causing too much humidity for the auto-defrost routine to keep up with.

Other causes could be a fan that is dead, as opposed to merely jammed with ice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Defrost heater not working right - ice builds up in duct to fridge
2. Controls for sending air to fridge not working, either temp sending or how the fridge responds to the temp.
3. Damper for allowing air to fridge not working
4. Fan that sends air to fridge not working

Modern fridges are crazy complicated due to energy conservation requirements.  Good luck.